# Freeform handwriting on iOS

Tags: iphone, ocr, textinput, handwriting

I would like to put handwriting as a text input to my project.

Is there any existing code or libraries that will help me accomplish this?
If not, is there an iPhone 4 has handwriting option like the chinese keyboard, which has handwriting tools, but in English?

As I  did some research, I couldn't find anything, maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places? Can somebody help me?

If possible, I would like the input delay to be less than a second, but a half of a second would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no handwriting recognition for the english language on iOS.
As for the delay - that's because the system needs to make calculations for the recognition - so no, there's nothing you can do about it.